# Finding A - B from two arrays using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have to filter out certain elements from an array in javascript and thought of using underscore.js for this purpose. As I am new to it,some help is appreciated.Please refer the code below , I have to find A \ B and assign the result to C . Does underscore.js has any convinience method to do that ?

```
function testUnderScore(){
    alert("underscore test");
    var a = [84, 99, 91, 65, 87, 55, 72, 68, 95, 42];
    var b = [ 87, 55, 72,42 ,13];
    var c = [];

    alert(c);
}
```

Comment: I just found it out , c= _.without(a, b); will yeild A-B , I will also check the below answers and accept them.

Comment: Note: You should better use the proper syntax [`A \ B`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setminus#Relative_complement) in text.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By using `difference` method:

```
var c = _.difference(a, b);
```

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#difference

Comment: is this different from _.without(a, b);  ?

Comment: @tito `.without()` takes the first argument as an array, then integers subsequently, which, given your circumstance here, might not be the one you need

Answer (score 2):

> I have to find A- B and assign the result to C . Does underscore.js
>   has any convinience method to do that ?

Yes, you can use `difference` [<sup>[View Docs]</sup>](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#difference) method:

```
var c = _.difference(a, b);
```

Comment: gives object not found ?  _.diff exists method exists ?

Comment: @tito: Use `difference` instead of `diff`. They have changed the method name in latest version.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var a = [1, 2, 5, 6], b = [6], c;

c = a.filter(
    function (aItem) {
        return !(~b.indexOf(aItem));
    }
);

console.log(c);
```

​
​

Comment: sorry, fixed bugs; ~ gives 0 on (-1), so indexOf is falsy ((-1) is not a falsy value)